# state null error using es6 computed state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in my jsx

```
<tr>
{!isEmpty(content) && content.map(o => {

                    if(o.sortKey){ console.log(this.state[`order${o.sortKey}`]) }
})}
</tr>
```

I couldn't run the app, When I commented the console.log line and do this instead `console.log(this.state); console.log(o.sortKey)`, I have `{ordercreated_at:'asc'}` and `created_at` but why my computed state has null error?

Comment: The key in state `ordercreated_at` and  the key you are looking up `created_at` are different, that looks like your problem.

Comment: @wgcrouch I have this `this.state[`order${o.sortKey}`] ` which concate order as prefix

Comment: ah true I missed that

Comment: is this code is inside a function or inside the `render` method?

Comment: Can you print value of o? What exactly is the error that you get?

Comment: In your code, replace this.state[`order${o.sortKey}`] with `this.state["ordercreated_at"]` and see if you still get a `NULL` error. In your shoes, I'd simplify the code until the error goes away, leaving the last change I made as the possible cause for the error.

Answer (score 0):

#### while calling map method you must return something.

`content.map (o => {  return (<span></span>)})`

here in map method return something and error will go away.